# System of Linear Equations using Mod

Tags: linear-algebra, modules, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I just want to check that I did a certain problem correctly. This is it:
$$a+b=3 \pmod{26}\\2a+b=7 \pmod{26}$$
Solve for $a$ and $b$

Now I setup the augmented matrix:
$$\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 3 \\
2 & 1 & 7  \end{array} \right]$$

After doing elementary row operations I get:
$$\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 4 \\
0 & 1 & -1  \end{array} \right]$$

That yields:
$$4-1=3\pmod{26}\\
8-1=7\pmod{26}$$

Did I do that correctly?

Comment: Yes you did ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @CharlieYabben : If you look at my edits, you will see how \pmod is used and how "displaye" TeX is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix manipulations are correct, but the interpretation of the answer isn't. After doing row operations, your matrix is the augmented matrix of the system
\begin{align*}
a \qquad & \equiv \phantom{-}4 \pmod{26} \\
\qquad b & \equiv -1 \pmod{26}.
\end{align*}
So that's your solution: $a\equiv4\pmod{26}$, $b\equiv-1\equiv25\pmod{26}$. You can check that this solution satisfies both original congruences (and also check that the solution you originally obtained does not).